# How do I write back to my Redis session store at the end of a SvelteKit request?

Tags: session, redis, sveltekit

I'm trying to write a simple session manager for SvelteKit using Redis as the store. I am using a `Handle` function in `hooks.server.ts`. As a simplified example,

```
export const sessionHook: Handle = async ({event, resolve}) => {

  const sid = event.cookies.get("mysid");

  const dataFromRedis = redisClient.hgetall(sid);

  for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(dataFromRedis)){
    event.locals[k] = v;
  }

  return await resolve(event);
}
```

This works great. All the session data is available in load functions. However, if the locals data is updated later in the request lifecycle, I don't know how to write that updated data back to Redis after my Handle function returns.

**How/when do I write the updated locals data back to my Redis store at the end of a request?**

At the end of the day, I'm just trying to replicate the 'autosave on session update' functionality of `express-session`. For example, I might want to invalidate a token in my session store using logic in a later component. I'd appreciate any guidance on this. I'm open to the idea that I'm misunderstanding something about the request lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I was confused about the request lifecycle. I don't need to return from Handle at the same time I resolve the request. I can store it, run my save, and return the response after saving.

```
...
// Process the rest of the request event.
const reponse = await resolve(event);

// Save my session which might have been changed elsewhere.
saveSession(locals);

// No more business in Handle.
return response;
```

This is a very obvious solution. I've had a hard time conceptualizing the line between frontend and backend with SvelteKit. I'll blame it on that :)